# Problem adding entity with Id = 0 in EntityFramworkCore.InMemory provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

Following code throws exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type
>   'DimEntity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same
>   key value for {'EntityEntityId'} is already being tracked. When
>   attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with
>   a given key value is attached

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("Test");
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
{
    //when I comment this line, the rest works file
    dbContext.DimEntity.Add(new DimEntity { EntityEntityId = 0, EntityKey = "Uknown" });


    //otherwise this line throws the exception
    dbContext.DimEntity.Add(new DimEntity { EntityEntityId = 1, EntityKey = "DFS Region" });
    = "Europe Region" }); 
   dbContext.DimEntity.Add(new DimEntity { EntityEntityId = 2, EntityKey = "Europe Region" });
}
```

Why?

Additional Details:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext (DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<DimEntity> DimEntity { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DimEntity>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.EntityEntityId);
            entity.ToTable("DimEntity", "mm");
            entity.Property(e => e.EntityEntityId).HasColumnName("Entity_EntityID");
        });
    }
}

public partial class DimEntity
{
    public int EntityEntityId { get; set; }
    public string EntityKey { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not in memory provider specific. By convention `int` PKs are considered auto increment (SqlServer `identity`), so the problem is similar to when adding explicit values to auto increment column.

If you keep your `new DimEntity { EntityEntityId = 0, ... }` in a variable, you'll see that after `Add` the value of the `EntityEntityId` will be 1 (because when the PK value is default (0 for `int`), the [value generation on add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties) is performed).

But when you add entity with non default `int` PK, no value generation occurs and the exception is thrown for `EntityEntityId = 1` because it already exist - the generated value for the first entity you've added first.

In general, if you don't want PK value generation, you should opt-in for that inside `OnModelCreating`:

```
entity.Property(e => e.EntityEntityId)
    .HasColumnName("Entity_EntityID")
    .ValueGeneratedNever(); // <--
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that you will always be explicitly assigning a value to the entity's ID field when creating it (i.e. in both your business logic and your test code), simply annotate your property with the [`DatabaseGeneratedAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute) set to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`:

```cs
public partial class DimEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EntityEntityId { get; set; }
    public string EntityKey { get; set; }
}
```

The three possible [`DatabaseGeneratedOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption) values `None`, `Identity`, `Computed` correspond to the fluent methods [`ValueGeneratedNever`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder-1.valuegeneratednever), [`ValueGeneratedOnAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder-1.valuegeneratedonadd), [`ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder-1.valuegeneratedonaddorupdate). The fluent syntax also offers [`ValueGeneratedOnUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder-1.valuegeneratedonupdate) which seems superfluous, but it's there if you need it.