# Why the special behaviour when FK identity is zero?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-3.1

I have three tables:

**UserProfiles** (UserId is the primary key

```
UserId Email
------ ------------
9032   bill@any.com
```

**WebpagesRoles** (RoleId is the primary key)

```
RoleId RoleName
------ ------------------
0      Site User
56     Admin
```

(Note the zero RoleId - that's the tricky bit.)

And **WebpagesUsersInRoles**, where both columns are foreign keys to the other tables.

I want to add these rows to WebpagesUsersInRoles

```
UserId RoleId
------ ------
9032   0
9032   56
```

My C#, EFCore 3.1 application has been deoptimised to aid investigation

```
        foreach (var uirToAdd in uirsToAdd)
        {
            _context.WebpagesUsersInRoles.Add(uirToAdd);
            // var role = _context.WebpagesRoles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RoleId == uirToAdd.RoleId);
            // uirToAdd.Role = role;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        }
```

The code snippet above can write the "Admin" row where RoleId is non-zero, but it can't write the "SiteUser" row where RoleId is zero.  It fails on the `SaveChangesAsync` with the message 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_RoleId"'.

However, if I uncomment those two lines, it works fine.

**Why?**

Note, we are not using `WebSecurity`, just the tables, and so a command like `roles.AddUserToRole("admin1", "Admin")` is not appropriate.  In any case, I'm just as curious about what's causing the problem as in finding a solution.

**Edit**

For reference, here's the actual model, including some parts I left out of the question for brevity:

```
public partial class WebpagesRole
{
    public WebpagesRole()
    {
        ActionDropdownRoles = new HashSet<ActionDropdownRole>();
        ActionTypeRoles = new HashSet<ActionTypeRole>();
        ClientTypeRoles = new HashSet<ClientTypeRole>();
        ScimUserGroupRoles = new HashSet<ScimUserGroupRole>();
        WebpagesUsersInRoles = new HashSet<WebpagesUsersInRole>();
    }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ActionDropdownRole> ActionDropdownRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ActionTypeRole> ActionTypeRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClientTypeRole> ClientTypeRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ScimUserGroupRole> ScimUserGroupRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WebpagesUsersInRole> WebpagesUsersInRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: 1- please write your model.
2- connection to database inside a loop is a very bad idea

Comment: You should never have 0 as primary key value when working with EF (actually, it should always be avoided). It's the CLR default and EF considers it as non existing.

Comment: Off-topic, as suggested above, avoid calling `SaveChanges` inside the loop. You should avoid the loop altogether and use `AddRange`, which is much faster.

Comment: @GertArnold, "you should never have 0 as a primary key when working with EF" - do you know of any docs explaining this?  From my of view, ir's a valid integer, and our system has functioned fine since 2016 with this value.  It seems EF is the only thing unhappy about zero.  Re the loop, as I mentioned in the question, this is "deoptimised code".  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @mostafakhoramnia, I've included the model.  You're right about it being a bad idea to save inside the loop.  It's like that to help me discover that zero is the heart of the problem.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Sure, 0 is a valid integer. There's even nothing that stops you from using negative numbers. It's just consensus to use numbers > 0. For example, the default identity seed value for SQL Server and Oracle is 1. Follow the principle of least surprise. EF is not the only ORM that would have problems with 0 PK values.

Comment: May it help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53416653/11143288?

Comment: @mostafakhoramnia, thanks - yes that does help - it makes it clear that 0 is considered as a special value.  If that was an answer, I'd upvote it and accept it.